# bad operand types for binary operator &

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, ternary

I am trying to print even and then odd using bitwise & operator, but don't why it is not working with ternary operator.

```
class Geeks {
     static void evenOdd (int a,int b) 
     {
     int e = (a&1==0)?a:b;// error: bad operand types for binary operator '&'
     System.out.println(e);
     int o = (a&1==1)?a:b;// error: bad operand types for binary operator '&'
     System.out.print(o);
     }
}
```

Comment: It's operator precedence. You should do `(a&1)==0`

Comment: `==` is stronger than `&`. Put braces around it: `if ((a&1) == 0) ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the precedence of operators being used.

Since == has higher precedence than &, 1==0 is evaluated. It evaluates to a boolean result. Since & is getting 2 operands - one boolean and one integer. It results in the compilation error as & can be performed on alike types.

It is the same reason why multiplication is performed before addition(known as BODMAS)

Parenthesis has to be used in such cases :

```
    System.out.println(e);
    int o = ((a&1)==1)?a:b;
    System.out.print(o);
```